# そうとして structure meaning

Tags: grammar

そして、　いま時代は大きく動きだそうとしていた

And now the time was about to/was going to change dramatically.

It's from Naruto. Kakashi is explaining how the Naruto universe works.

I'm not sure what として does here.
Is it the particle と marking "a manner of doing something" + する. If so, what does する mean here?
or is it として as in "as?"

Comment: Might be this  [とする](https://itazuraneko.neocities.org/grammar/dojg/dojgpages/intermediate%E3%81%A8%E3%81%99%E3%82%8B2.html)

Comment: Isn't it 動き**だ**そうとして**いた** or something? Please double check the spelling, or please paste the original page.

Comment: That's what I heard. My listening skills are that good. I'm pretty sure I can't hear だ there.

Comment: @LonelyDriver thanks for the link! Definitely not. I know this one. [sounds] + to + suru. It's like saying "make a sound" Cows make moo moo [sound].

Comment: @naruto I had some of my friends listen to this part and they hear だ and いた. Just like you wrote. I can't hear it at all. But still, it doesn't make things any clearer.